# what does the '{}' mean ? StringFormat='{}{0:MM/dd/yyyy}'

Tags: xaml

I'm new to c# and xaml, but I don't understand the usage of '**{}**' in the following code:

```
StringFormat='{}{0:MM/dd/yyyy}'
```

because I also see code like :

```
FormatString="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mmtt"
```

which has no **braces**.

I'm really confused, is it a c# syntax I am not aware?

Fei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The escape sequence ({}) is used so that an open brace ({)can be used as a literal character in XAML.

Besides it can also be use to replacing the contents in format string with actual parameters.

In example below they are replaced in a format string with actual arguments, something like:

```
format ("My name is {1:s}{0:s}", "Diablo", "Pax");
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a [XAML escape sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744986(v=vs.110).aspx) used to prevent the subsequent opening brace from being interpreted as a XAML markup extension.